# does garbage collector set the reference to null when it collects an object?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we want to pass a managed String object to a Win32 function and I just pass `IntPtr` of this string object to the native function, but before the native function uses the address of passed string object, the garbage collector collects the string object because there is no root to reference the string object in the managed code any more.

My question is, does Garbage Collector set the reference of string object to null or leave it untouched so the referenc might point to sth else? if it is former, the native function can do a null check, if it is the latter, then native function can do nothing about it and might touch sth it shouldn't touch.

Comment: It leaves it untouched -- the GC doesn't know that the `IntPtr` points to a string. The `IntPtr` will start pointing to garbage, and bad things will happen if it's dereferenced. Note that the GC can collect an object even if there's still a reference on the stack to it, which is why `GC.KeepAlive` exists. It is your responsibility to make sure that objects which native code has IntPtrs to aren't GC'd

Comment: When you pass `IntPtr` to the native function, the native function got a copy of the reference. Changes to the `IntPtr` you have in C# wouldn't be reflected on the native function. Thus, Even if the GC would update the `IntPtr`, the native code would not know.

Comment: Also note that `IntPtr` are value struct which mans they are _all_ copies of something.

Comment: The GC can only collect an object when there are no references left, so there's nothing to be set to null.  The far more insidious problem is it compacting the heap, moving objects in memory.  Which will make the native code fail miserably and utterly undiagnosably.

Answer (score 1):

The GC tracks references to managed objects. An `IntPtr` is not a reference to a managed object, it is just an arbitrary value. It is therefore invisible to the GC and cannot be updated, since the GC does not know if it points to a managed object, some unmanaged memory, or something else entirely. If the GC did somehow know that it pointed to a managed object it could treat it as any other managed reference and avoid collecting the object in the first place.

I believe that anytime you use an pointer to managed memory you need to use [pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning) to ensure that the object is not collected or moved.

There is also [Gc.KeepAlive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=net-5.0) to ensure objects owning unmanaged resources have a lifetime longer than the usage of said resources. Say an object owning umanaged memory and a finalizer that releases said memory. You could take a pointer to the unmanaged memory, and if it was the last usage of the object, the finalizer of the object could be called, releasing the memory.

Comment: It's worth noting that that finalizer issue is a bit worse than your answer makes out: it's possible for a class to have a method which passes an `IntPtr` to a native method, and a finalizer which frees the thing the `IntPtr` points to, **and the finalizer is called while that native method is executing**. That's *really* hard to combat, and it's one of the main reasons that `SafeHandle` exists, and a really good reason to always always use a `SafeHandle` to represent unmanaged resources. Not directly applicable to OP as their `IntPtr` points to a managed resource though